# Showing function of two variables is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions

So I have the function $f(x,y(x)) = \sqrt{|x(1-y(x)^2)|}$ and I want to show that it is an increasing function of $x$ for $y\neq1$ and for $x\geq0$. So what I did first was split into two cases where $1-y(x)^2$ is postive and negative respectively. Then I took the total derivative of $f(x,y(x))$ and tried to show it was positive. But when I done this I kept having a $y'(x)$ crop up which I have no information about so couldn't reach the required conclusion. Am I going along the right path?

Comment: Don't you **only** need to check the partial derivative wrt $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: Are you sure you've written the equation for $f$ correctly? (Shouldn't the LHS be $f(x, y)$? The brackets don't balance on the RHS.) Is $y$ a function or a number?

Comment: Fixed the bracket inbalance, and thats what I wasn't sure about, if I only need to check the partial derivative then I can do that. But as $y$ is a function of $x$ I would've thought I couldn't just treat that as a constant?